DKIM Record Externally Readable Yet Emails Not DKIM Signed
I have a VPS and launched my own mail server on it using Postfix & Dovecot.
Emails are now going in and out of my self-hosted mail server.
I created reverse A, SPF, DMARC and DKIM records for ease of acceptance by recipient hosts, as is the norm these last 10 years. Here is my DKIM in essence:
v=DKIM1;g=*;h=sha256;k=rsa;n=Created: June 2024;s=email;p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAt5cWc+MExfhaVWlgSA6QTtoSkvTnyqe4dAb3G5x036aqN3Z+vhzFp80/bL7HuNLv0LppbqvF4U9tSvM/Sggyqv148YGwjT0/Btx6KagIF3r+bRc7VAhu8qbuNr7gALX8xNM+gLbKe19CeJus2q7/sftDR/xHDjqRwubnG3WCwRh7T0oE8UcWpP0tvy47ttriZzOsE0wQ+NWT15Hze5Jqcnc4IpbMMiHuSIainkl7eGFni1DU2mLaTtp36RDcJEywgFY/12Ci49Ii9oLRpwyMVKrtH/xR2ZJAOCm5jO5EDx4lhp7kJ8KuL8QoWYYWMRix8zVnWgc+123uWQHQwEocMwIDAQAB;t=s;

Ordinary mail filter tests like mxtoolbox.com find my DKIM AOK, i.e. the DKIM record is published from my DNS, valid and a public key is obtainable.
Yet when I look at the headers of emails sent from my Thunderbird client via my VPS mail server to say a Gmail account, all I see are "ARC-Seal" and "ARC-Message-Signature":
    ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1719582028; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=J7qsTyRGpAGh1V8JWpN4RgFJWi5PWCVmHZnCf/ZMU42mx8jCYsU5PCx+Q3p3W0+8lS
         mnKRFZDKkx4iv0kkaRI7XObevMfzO+SpXDFb6sB5HmpX+R8yEWQegYG8yjF66Cs8Fu6r
         OTW/gSmLo0oLUW6vCq3oKxfGU1clCYxsVaZwP80C04jjD/kOxfQfSB6teV2ooPYDs41h
         QLHiqNitDo72KdpyHJMtn8loo08/cc23uBVJqknCuk7sT08MtRiOQS+WgTm5E6kR2QPI
         HlbnCKYdlfgsDNqEHbIClZSbari6L7/2vDRr8N1YhNhrpHcVU9hiP7vHcJ6VsM4EkgdV
         tb+A==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=subject:from:to:content-language:user-agent:mime-version:date
         :message-id;
        bh=COanYjz2uJUNNmCGV2PKQgWykhpQQ81vARHHTm+ASdM=;
        fh=+z5YwS1fKhOqDjO/eSCIwHEOPWX1F6gC2Yt9II/NC6g=;
        b=VSXdlftuQH1xRY/lBPwtE3+msmRUXVMMExLhdO8vSkz5ya4AZRtuFrt5Gtes/wQvfZ
         O1vR+TLko19zkOEiiqFn6X/A1xIWCljzQPKcGoPkcKeVdhoEDVTmf5SY/g50Otdx/+fi
         XqJrzD0OMNqDYaugolmg27nbjz+jhq2JSCtN+8j26fab0nbNioQDZRUP97MX4N1PHIOI
         /pcgyc5NO7YZwErQ27n0gkiMijZCrlNEjA0fJlBABYaDgNm7KJ31wZJxoF6N4WhRjvrI
         2NUI8kZKcfPew9MLsCgmVdDONuo/YZPr7h0WkVwwQ8zsJQATHYJ0LF7YaO2Rt8xFvWZr
         uP0Q==;
        dara=google.com
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of abc@xyz.com designates xx.xx.xx.xxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=abc@xyz.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=abc@xyz.com

I am wondering if my ISP (from whom I lease the VPS) is relaying on my emails and automatically turning the DKIM signatures and seals into ARC ones.
I also ran an actual email to this domain https://www.learndmarc.com  which validates mail filters. Below is the output on DKIM and DMARC:
I see you haven't included a DKIM signature. Therefore, I am unable to authenticate the email and determine if the message was altered during transit. The Auth Result is none.

I've found the following DMARC policy at _dmarc.xyz.com: "v=DMARC1;p=reject;pct=100;rua=mailto:abc@xyz.com;sp=reject;aspf=s;".
Found policy: reject.

The DMARC record does not specify the 'adkim' element, causing it to default to 'r' (relaxed).
This means that any subdomains are ignored by the alignment check. In relaxed mode, foo.example.com aligns with bar.example.com. In strict mode, the alignment will fail.

Can my host be effectively be disabling my DKIM signatures before relaying them onwards ?

Have you actually configured your mta to sign messages?

No. I assumed it was implicit like the DMARC and SPF. Good point. I'll see to it.

It isn't. For one thing you have to tell it what private keys to use. And really, you should reconsider hosting e-mail on your own. It's a unforgiving service. A single mistake and you're blacklisted.

Your DKIM record in DNS allows receiving servers to validate the DKIM signature in your outgoing emails. Hence, your outgoing emails have to be DKIM signed. Having only the DKIM record in DNS with no DKIM signing of the outgoing email isn't enough.

Redid everything and it carries the DKIM signatures as well as ARC ones now when an email is sent to a Gmail account. Many thanks, vidarlo and joeqwerty. Should I delete this thread ?
